# c# преобразовать Db DataReader в Dictionary

Tags: c#, база-данных

беру инфу из базы, при получении полей получаются много
`dreader["field_name"].ToString()`
можно ли перевести сразу DataReader в Dictionary чтобы избавиться от кучи ToString()?:
`drDict["field_name"]`

UPD:

сделал так:
`Dictionary<string, object> drDict;
drDict = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).ToDictionary(dr.GetName, dr.GetValue);`
но value получается object, опять надо его кастить в string

Comment: сразу это как ?

Comment: @tym32167 добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ну так кастите вот тут `dr.GetValue.ToString()`

Comment: @tym32167 'OleDbDataReader.GetValue(int)" является метод, который недопустим в данном контексте
`ToDictionary(dr.GetName, (string)dr.GetValue)` тоже ошибка

Comment: Ну у вас же до этого как то работало, вот к тому, как работало, добавьте `.ToString()`

Comment: @tym32167 "чтобы избавиться от кучи ToString()?" это было изначальным требованием к задаче

Comment: вы написали, что у вас вот это работает `drDict = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).ToDictionary(dr.GetName, dr.GetValue);`, я вам и говорю, если оно работает, то в конце вот этого `dr.GetValue` поставьте `.ToString()`

Comment: `ToDictionary(dr.GetName, n => dr.GetValue(n).ToString())`?

Comment: А главное, у `DataReader` есть метод `GetString`.

Comment: Не хотите попробовать dapper? Получите сразу нужные типы - и не только строки, но и Int'ы, даты и т.п.